# How can I debug a USB HID device that does not come with a driver?

Tags: usb, driver, hid

I have a [single button USB controller](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wH3FoGl-Ix8), but it did not come with any drivers (simply a Windows program that communicates with it directly for its intended purpose).

**USB Fidget**
Vendor ID: 0x1d34
Product ID: 0x0001
Product name: DL100A Dream Cheeky Generic Controller

So, I would like to be able to read whether or not the button is being pressed. My main development environment is Mac, but I'd like the solution to run on Windows too. So ideally a cross platform solution would be best.

I can find [pieces](http://www.johnbruin.net/index.php/2008/11/30/new-software-for-your-usb-panic-button/) [of](https://github.com/derrick/dream_cheeky) [code](http://www.lunarlamp.co.uk/usb-panic-button-linux) for other devices by the same manufacturer but there are differences in Product ID so the code does not work and I lack understanding to change anything other than the vendor/product.

As far as I understand it I need to poll the USB device with a feature request packet?

Is there some software I can use to "watch" the USB device so I can see what is actually happening when I press the button? If not, how would I go about writing some myself?

Answer (score 2):

basically on MacOs very huge amount of usb devices work through IOUserClient. This standart class provide to user mode programs ability to control device without kernel mode driver (by using usermode part of IOKit framework). To sniff for usb packets you can use USB Prober, start from this article http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1370/_index.html

On windows standart way - standart USB driver + standart HID driver, no need in specific vendor driver if they not develop some additional functionality over standart. You can use any of commercial or freeware tools to sniff usb packets - like this one http://www.hhdsoftware.com/usb-monitor

Comment: USB Prober shows me a lot of information, including the interrupt endpoint that I need to check. But the information is the same regardless of the state of the button. So I still have no idea how to proceed. Will check the Windows software...

Comment: Need to compile IOUSBFamilly with logging support. IOKit don`t provide filtering capabilities in driver stack =(. Windows approach is most simple of couse

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any cross platform way to handle it. This is the presentation I point people to for how to create a driver app for a random piece of HID hardware:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=207

Comment: The part germain to writing a HID driver starts on slide 44.

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded the PDF.

I've also made some headway with the Ruby code I linked above. I did some Sniffing in Windows and found the values the device returns. So now it's just a matter of wrapping that information cross platform using libusb.

Comment: @ThaneNorton Do you happen to have the actual source code for the example you showed in that presentation?

Answer (score 1):

For testing / accessing HID devices, i.e.

- Get Feature Report (matt's original question)
- Sending Feature Reports
- Sending Output Reports
- Receiving Input reports

I'd suggest the "HIDAPI Test Tool" / "testgui" included in the great cross-platform HID library from [signal11/hidapi](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/).

On Windows you require an additional [3rd party package](https://github.com/downloads/signal11/hidapi/hidapi-externals.zip) to compile the testgui application, but it was pretty easy and the GUI tool was more straightforward that other code examples and tools I saw. (I could cross-check if I am maybe allowed to publish a VS2008 compiled version of this.)

Another free option for sending output reports and receiving input reports, is our own "Docklight" tool (in evaluation mode, unlimited time, just no storing), see [Docklight Scripting HID USB](http://docklightnews.blogspot.com/2014/02/debugging-usb-hid-applications.html).